# Access to Application Context from Grails Filter Constructor

Tags: grails, before-filter

How can I access the **Application Context** from a Grails **Filter**.  I am able to do so from a Controller by using the following:

```
def ctx = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext
```

But in a Filter ctx is null.

In this case, I'm specifically trying to access the application context in the Filter's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the holder classes - they're deprecated in 2.0 and will be removed in a future release.

The best way to access the application context from a controller, filter, service, etc. is to add a dependency injection for the GrailsApplication, i.e

```
def grailsApplication
```

Then you can get the context via

```
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
```

It's unusual to do work in a constructor that's related to Spring beans, so if possible you should refactor. Grails artifacts are Spring beans, so they're instantiated while the application context is being constructed.

Controllers are a bit different since they're not singletons like most beans, so by the time they get constructed (one per request) the holders are populated. But in general you should avoid doing GORM work, accessing the application context, etc. in a constructor since it's unlikely that things are wired up yet.